Chef. Issues trying to run Knife bootstrap an ubuntu 22.04 node from a windows chef workstation
I am a bit desperate trying to make a simple knife bootstrap of a linux node (ubuntu 22.04) using chef workstation (0.42) installed in my windows PC.
The commnad I am trying to execute is:
knife bootstrap u-wks01.antmind.org   -N u-wks01 -ssh-user test --connection-password 'XXXXXXX' -U   test --use-sudo-password -V -V

And the error that I get is:
DEBUG: [SSH] test@u-wks01.antmind.org<{:user_known_hosts_file=>"/dev/null", :port=>22, :compression=>false, :compression_level=>0, :keepalive=>true, :keepalive_interval=>60, :timeout=>60, :auth_methods=>["none", "password", "keyboard-interactive"], :keys_only=>nil, :keys=>[], :password=>"<hidden>", :forward_agent=>nil, :non_interactive=>true, :verify_host_key=>:accept_new}> (sh /tmp/chef_GXlNnZ/bootstrap.sh)
 [u-wks01.antmind.org] bash: line 1: $'\r': command not found
 [u-wks01.antmind.org] bash: line 2: $'\r': command not found
 [u-wks01.antmind.org] bash: line 3: $'\r': command not found
 [u-wks01.antmind.org] bash: line 4: $'\r': command not found
 [u-wks01.antmind.org] bash: -c: line 15: syntax error near unexpected token `$'{\r''
'ash: -c: line 15: `exists() {
 [u-wks01.antmind.org]
ERROR: The following error occurred on u-wks01.antmind.org:
ERROR:
DEBUG: [SSH] test@u-wks01.antmind.org<{:user_known_hosts_file=>"/dev/null", :port=>22, :compression=>false, :compression_level=>0, :keepalive=>true, :keepalive_interval=>60, :timeout=>60, :auth_methods=>["none", "password", "keyboard-interactive"], :keys_only=>nil, :keys=>[], :password=>"<hidden>", :forward_agent=>nil, :non_interactive=>true, :verify_host_key=>:accept_new}> (rm -f "/tmp/chef_GXlNnZ/bootstrap.sh")


I checked the default bash of the user test in the linu node and changed from dash to bash.

Checked chef-full.erb file with VSCode and change CRLF to LF.

Changed the initial line of the code (copying it to another template)  from sh -c '' to bash -c ''.

Used dos2unix to convert the .erb file


But I still get the same error.
I do understand that the error is related to how Windows and Unix type systems end the line (\r\n vs \r) but I am not able to find a solution.
